# Eigenvalues containing a variable

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Are $\cos(ax)$ and $\exp(ax^2)$ ($a$ is a constant) eigenfunctions of
>
> (a) operator $\displaystyle\frac{d^2}{dx^2}?$
> (b) operator $\dot{x}?$
>
> What are the corresponding eigenvalues if applicable?

From what I understood an eigenvalue of an eigenfunction must be a constant. I thought $\cos(ax)$ would be an eigenfunction of the second derivative operator but that’s it?

Since the others, when the operator is applied, give the original operand multiplied by a term containing a variable (and in the case of the second derivative of $\mathrm e^ax^2$ a sum of $2a + 4a^2 x^2).$

I wanted to check my reasoning was correct that an ‘eigenvalue’ must not contain a variable, in this case $x?$ Is $x$ a variable here?

Comment: If the operation returns the same function with the variable out front, it's not an eigenfunction.

Comment: How do you understand the operator $\dot{x}$ here? What does it do?

Comment: @S.Farr I edited the question changing the notation while typing text from an image. If it helps, the [original](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/revisions/146758/1) was looking like ‘$x\cdot$’.

Comment: It looks to me like they meant the operator 'multiplication with $x$'? But it is clear that in this case neither of your examples are eigenfunctions of this operator.

Comment: @S.Farr If you think that multiplication better fits the question, please feel free to edit it. It's not really my field of expertise. In fact, this is quite plausible since the OP's book of problems is quite liberal in terms of notations (judging from other questions on Chemistry.SE). For example, it uses Greek letter Theta to denote standard state (e.g. $\Delta G^\Theta$), when it should be $\Delta G^\circ$ or $\Delta G^⦵.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be some finite dimensional vector space and $\Phi$ a linear operator on $V$. Then an element $x\in V$ is an eigenvector (or in your case called eigenfunction) of $V$ if there is a constant $\lambda$ such that $\Phi(x) = \lambda x$.

In your case, we have $\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \cos(ax) = -\frac{d}{dx} a\sin(ax) = -a^2\cos(ax)$. Therefore, $\cos(ax)$ is an eigenfunction of the double derivative with eigenvalue $-a^2$.

For the second function, we get $\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \exp(ax^2) = \frac{d}{dx} 2ax \cdot \exp(ax^2) = 2a \cdot \exp(ax^2) + (2ax)^2 \cdot \exp(ax^2) = (2a+4a^2x^2)\cdot \exp(ax^2)$, which is not of the form $\lambda \exp(ax^2)$, so this is not an eigenfunction to this operator.